# Navigation Drawer Crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

after days and days, I managed to have the navigation drawer working, following also the recent updates in Android Studio.

Here is the activity where I am developing it (it's called "**Two**"): http://pastebin.com/r9h6vDaT
I also have some further coding related to start ActivityForResult and one expandableListView but nothing relevant to the case

The **layout** I associated is http://pastebin.com/uJUpRRbq.

The fragment I am inflating are named progressively **First_Fragment** etc and they are all linked to a layout **first_layout** etc
One sample of **Fragment Activity** is http://pastebin.com/RgjCjzYb

Now, what's the **problem**?

Being the code like these above, it just crashes before opening the activity because of "setSupportActionBar(toolbar);".--->**Reason**: "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.".

Fair enough, I deleted it and of course it invalidates the Drawerlayout that follows, so I delete that block too (from "DrawerLayout drawer =" to "toggle.syncState();")

and it sort of works.

Now, no toggles, I slide with the finger, but if I click on the first entry, it crashes.
Yet, with the DisplayView method, I stated which fragments have to be opened.
Of course I did not register the classes in Manifest.

All in all, the app does not work yet, and the rest of the layouts and documents come from the Android Template.

Any idea?

(hopefully useful) update: I set the nobartheme in manifest, but it doesn't help

Comment: As suggested, use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar or use windowActionBar=false in your style.